# centralizr elementos "a" em uma div

Tags: html, css

Como faço para centralizar um link "a" horizontalmente e verticalmente no centro de uma div?

```
 <div id="header_right">
    <a>A</a>
    <a>B</a>
    <a>C</a>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header_right {
    width: 342px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicione no css:

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Verdade, editei a resposta para adicionar o vertical.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="header_right">
 <table width="100%" height="100%">
     <tr valing="middle" align="center">
         <td><a>A</a></td>
         <td><a>B</a></td>
         <td><a>C</a></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```